# How can I detect reactions?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm attempting to make an offer command in which the bot detects whether the mentioned user reacts with check or x.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach")
async def offer(ctx, member:discord.Member, reaction):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="<a:Loading:768095883664424971> Incoming Offer", value=f"The <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> have offered {member.mention}.")
    offer_sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>")
    await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:XMark:768095331555606528>")
    await member.send("You have been offered to the <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>. You have 30 minutes to accept/decline.")
    await asyncio.sleep(1800) # Replace "30" with 1800, because 1800 in seconds is 30 min.
    await offer_sent.delete()
    def on_reaction(reaction, member:discord.Member):
        channel = member.channel

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == member and str(reaction.emoji) == '<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>'
      
        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send(f"{member.mention} hasn't reacted in time.")
        else:
            await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has accepted <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> offer.")
```

Comment: Simply don't make that `on_reaction` function, leave the code that's inside it and put it in the same level of indentation as everything else

Comment: When I do this, I get an error saying "discord.ext.commads.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: reaction is a required argument that is missing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the reaction from the offer function as I have no clue what it did as it wasn't used in the code. Then I removed the `on_reaction` function but moved the code from inside it before the `asyncio.sleep(1800)`.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Franchise Owner", "General Manager", "Head Coach")
async def offer(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="<a:Loading:768095883664424971> Incoming Offer", value=f"The <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> have offered {member.mention}.")
    offer_sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>")
    await offer_sent.add_reaction("<a:XMark:768095331555606528>")
    await member.send("You have been offered to the <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>. You have 30 minutes to accept/decline.")
    channel = ctx.channel

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == member and str(reaction.emoji) == '<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>'

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await channel.send(f"{member.mention} hasn't reacted in time.")
    else:
        await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has accepted <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592> offer.")
    await asyncio.sleep(1800) # Replace "30" with 1800, because 1800 in seconds is 30 min.
    await offer_sent.delete()
```